# How to disable Cufon on certain elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cufon

I currently use Cufon accross our site with something similar to `Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'DIN Medium').replace('h1');` Now for a single H1 tag i would like Cufon to be disabled, this is without changing the H1 tag to any other tag, it must remain as it is.

I can add classes etc to the H1 tag if required, and can do any HTML/CSS/JS just not changing the actual tag.

Anyone know if this is possible and if it is how?

Thanks in advance,

Shadi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on which selector engine you use, you can:

- add a class to your exception h1 element
- you can use the :not selector to only apply cufon to the h1's that don't have the aforementioned class (with jQuery and classname 'clean' it would be something like `Cufon.replace('h1:not(.clean)');`

Comment: Genious solution! Exactly what I needed:)

Comment: Can you make fiddle for it, I didn't get answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
function remove_cufon(selector) {
    $(selector).html( cufon_text(selector) );
    return true;
}

function cufon_text(selector) {
    var g = '';
    $(selector +' cufon cufontext').each(function() {
        g = g + $(this).html();
    }); 
    return $.trim(g);
}
```

Usage:

```
remove_cufon('#name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery: Use the css class to h1 and specify in the selector...

```
$('h1.noCufon').each(function(){
        var cufonText = '';
        $('cufontext',$(this)).each(function(){
            cufonText+=$(this).html();
        });
    if(cufonText!=''){
        $(this).html(cufonText);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

by single h1 you mean?

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    if($(this).siblings('h1').length)
        Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'DIN Medium').replace(this);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, you are telling Cufon to replace all the h1 elements again. You can send the DOM element though.

Comment: This will just style all H1 tags.