# Disable cufon on selected element

Tags: element, cufon

Is there a way to disable cufon on all elements in selected div? Almost on whole page I use cufon. But I want one div to be in Arial. Is there any way? I've tried something like element:not(.class) but without any results.

Comment: Please check the answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738303/how-to-disable-cufon-on-certain-elements#answer-5034882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I'm trying to do this as well, seem to have found a solution! Make use of jQuery's :not selector:

```
 Cufon.replace('h1, h2:not(.question), .pageheader', { 
 color: '-linear-gradient(white, #777777)', 
 fontFamily: 'Unisans', 
 textShadow: '-2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1)' });
```

This excludes the class h2.question from the cufon replace in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and IE at least. :)

Comment: @Jednoduchy, I missed that you said you'd tried my solution previously without results: ("I've tried something like element:not(.class)"). What specifically did you try? When I added double and single quotes inside the :not() parentheses, I didn't have any luck, but removing them fixed my issue.