# how to disable cufon styles for h2 tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grails, cufon

I am using cufon fonts for div, h2 span etc. elements. i want to disable the cufon for particular tags like h2, span.

how can i replace the cufon to disable.

in project the cufon usage is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<j2:akamaize dir="js/cufon" file="cufon-yui.js?av=VrZj" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<j2:akamaize dir="js/cufon" file="ITC_Avant_Garde_Gothic_Std_550-ITC_Avant_Garde_Std_Md_700-font.js" />"></script>
<script>
    Cufon.replace('fieldset.form div.field label, h2,.question, .step-text-1, .step-text-2, .step-text-3, .dumcuf', {fontFamily: 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std'});
 </script>
```

anybody have idea is very helpful

Thanks 
arnagendla.

Answer (score 0):

just add a class to your exception h2, span elements

More details here ==>
[How to disable Cufon on certain elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738303/how-to-disable-cufon-on-certain-elements)